# Next.js - using component level scss (component.module.scss) changing only the parent class to use style['className']

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, next.js

I'm currently trying to find a way to use component level scss on next.js using https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-component-level-css

without having to define all my classes using "style['className']", only the first one.

Example:
JSX:

```
<Parent className={style['parent-class-name']}>
 <Child className="child">
   Example
 </Child>
</Parent>
```

SCSS:

```
.parent-class-name{
  .child{
    text-decoration: underline;
    transform: rotate(-7deg);
  }
}
```

but I have been unable to find a way for now and I ended up building a function to automatically define the items using the 'classnames' library (If you are interested, I will leave it here)

```
 import classNames from 'classnames';

const classNameGenerator = (classString,styleObject) => {
    let classList = classString.split(" ");
    classList = classList.map( classItems => styleObject[classItems] || classItems);
    return classNames(...classList);
}

export default classNameGenerator;
```

is there any alternative to this?

Thanks and have a nice rest of the day!

Comment: Are you using the `[filename].module.scss` convention mentioned in [Next.js SASS support docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#sass-support)?

Comment: Yes, and that is working, however, I don't want to use the "style['class-name'] for every component defined in the sass file, I want to use it on the parent class for the component,  so parentClass_nextSufix, and then define all my other classes as "classList='my-normal-class'" and inherit all the child classes from the module.scss file, if that make sense ^^' the example about should be pretty self-explanatory hopefully